# is it possible to down cast from parent class pointer to child class pointer inside a second child class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

There are three classes `a`,`b` and `c` namely.
Both `b` and `c` are children of `a`.
Is there a way to downcast from a pointer of `a` to the pointer of `b` inside of class `c`?

Hope I explained myself correctly.
Thanks for the Help in advance.

Comment: _"hope i explained myself correctly ."_ What about example code of what you intend to do? Way better and concise than prose.

Comment: Being "inside of class `c`" should make no more difference than being inside one function or another. If you're having a problem with your attempt to downcast, there might be details in how you're doing it or in your specific situation that aren't captured in an abstract description of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "is it possible..." is yes.

However, the need for it indicates bad design. Anything you are going to do with the down-cast pointer should be done via virtual functions.

In rare cases that you need it (please explain your use case to see if it is one of those), you should use C++ `dynamic_cast<>`, and not a C-style cast.

The bigger issue in your design is - class `c` should NOT be aware of class `b`.

Answer (score -2):

```
Class C : public A {
... 
   A* x1;
   B* b1 = (B*)x1;
// or
   A x2;
   B* b2 = (B*)(&x2);
...
}
```

Comment: Do not use C style casts.